# How to use pandoc filter to change a RawBlock to RawInline?

Tags: filter, pandoc

I am now using pandoc to convert markdown to HTML. I would like to convert some inline LaTeX environment to, for example, SVG. I could do this for RawBlocks, by using a Pandoc filter to transform `RawBlock` to `Para [Image]`. But I have a problem:

```
➜ pandoc -R -t native
A command \foo{bar}. An environment \begin{test} test \end \end{test} appears here.         

\begin{rawblock}
test
\end{rawblock}

[Plain [Str "A",Space,Str "command",Space,RawInline (Format "tex") "\\foo{bar}",Str ".",Space,Str "An",Space,Str "environment"]
,RawBlock (Format "latex") "\\begin{test} test \\en \\end{test}"
,Para [Str "appears",Space,Str "here."]
,RawBlock (Format "latex") "\\begin{rawblock}\ntest\n\\end{rawblock}"]
```

As shown above, inline environment will also be parsed as `RawBlock` rather than `RawInline`, hence the text after the inline environment will become a new paragraph.

So my question is:

Is it feasible to take inline LaTeX environment to `RawInline`, like how Pandoc deal with inline command.

How to implement this using a Pandoc filter (better in python)?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about this not-really-an-answer, but I can't comment yet.

Pandoc has a predefined list of environments that it recognizes as inline. All other environments default to block-level. Since LaTeX is rather lax with its syntax concerning block-level environments, pandoc really has no way to know if a given environment is inline or block-level.

If you *really* want to use LaTeX environments, you can, but writing context-sensitive python filter is not exactly easy (it's somewhat easier with Haskell, but I assume that's not an option)

There is, however, an easier option: use `span`s instead of inline LaTeX environments and `div`s instead of block-level ones. Syntax is a bit more clunky, but writing a filter that will work with spans with a given class is relatively simple with any supported language.

```
pandoc -t native <<< "Replace inline environments with spans: <span class='span-class'>like this</span>"
[Para [Str "Replace",Space,Str "inline",Space,Str "environments",Space,Str "with",Space,Str "spans:",Space,Span ("",["span-class"],[]) [Str "like",Space,Str "this"]]]
```